# Convert java springboot code into scala akka http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I want to convert my REST Api code which is written with java spring boot in to scala akka http ,is there any online converter available for this?

Comment: Do you really think there is an automagic converter that works between these two such different framework that you won't find on the top position of the result from your favorite search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't really find any "online converter" that will do you the job. I suggest either to take sometime to learn Scala or copy that code that you have into the your Scala IDE (such as Intellij or so), that will automatically make syntax changes to your code, but you still have to do some changes for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No. That's a lot to expect from an automated service.